# Why does points disappear occasionally

Tags: discussion

This is my first question at **meta**. Well as the subject explains, why does points disappear sometimes without even leaving any tracks. I'm not sure this has been asked before or may be answered in a different manner. But I've noticed this at times that my points are been reduced down to certain amount. And when I check my profile for any down votes un-accept answer or any other shows nothing at all.

What could be the reason for this??

Comment: When you go to your reputation tab, at the very bottom of the list there is a checkbox saying `Show removed posts`, is that checked?

Comment: @Dan No it wasn't :)

Comment: Thank you for the hook-up.. BTW, when removing the posts completely, it removes the whole points that I've been awarded, is it??

Comment: Yes all awarded points for that post will be reverted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Dan suggests, the drop *is* from edit suggestions on posts that are now deleted.
The deletion starts a cascade removal of all reputation people earn from a question.

There's not much more I can say. I personally don't think it's fair (you put in the time to improve these posts) but there are occasions when not doing it would also not be fair.

All I can say is to just be more careful about *what* you edit. Don't edit terminally bad posts. If it can't be answered after editing, you should be flagging it for removal.

Comment: What else I could say after reading this. I do not care about points that I earn when it comes to helping but it is somewhat interests/motivates a user to see their points increase. I was curious to know where these points have gone & why. Now that I know, it makes sense. Further I'd give you `+1 million` for the last paragraph!! That is indeed a good advise. :)